Squares on top of each other inside a circle

I am wondering if anyone can make any more progress on this problem?
Consider the image above. The circle has radius 1. What is the sum of the areas of the infinite collection of squares?
Here is my attempt at the solution
Define the side length of the n$^{th}$ largest square to be $\hat{a}_n$. This means that the largest square has a side length of $\hat{a}_1$, and the next square a side length of $\hat{a}_2$. It is clear that $\hat{a}_1 = \sqrt{2}$.
Now we will find $\hat{a}_{n+1}$ given $\hat{a}_1,...\hat{a}_{n}$.
Consider the right angled triangle formed from the vertices of: 1) the centre of the circle, 2) the vertex of square $n+1$ that lies on the circumference of the circle and 3) A vertex on the midpoint of the horizontal edge of square $n+1$. We can see that the two perpendicular side lengths of this right angled triangle are
\begin{equation}
\frac{\hat{a}_{n+1}}{2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\hat{a}_2+\cdots + \hat{a}_{n+1}
\end{equation}
Now define (simply to make calculations easier) $a_1 := \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $a_n := \hat{a}_n   \forall   n\geq 2$
Now the perpendicular side lengths of this right angled triangle are
\begin{equation}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_{i}
\end{equation}
Now Pythagoras tells us that
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{a_{n+1}}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i\right)^2 = 1
\end{equation}
$\implies$
\begin{equation}
\frac{(a_{n+1})^2}{4} + \left(a_{n+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right)^2 = 1
\end{equation}
$\implies$
\begin{equation}
\frac{5}{4}(a_{n+1})^2 + 2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right)a_{n+1}+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right)^2 = 1
\end{equation}
$\implies$
\begin{equation}
5(a_{n+1})^2 + 8\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right)a_{n+1}+4\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right)^2 -4 = 0
\end{equation}
Now we can solve for $a_{n+1}$ using the quadratic formula:
\begin{equation}
\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation}
$\implies$
\begin{equation}
a_{n+1} = \frac{-8\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\pm\sqrt{\left(8\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right)^2-20\left(4\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right)^2 -4\right)}}{10}
\end{equation}
Simplify and taking the positive solution we obtain the following formula:
\begin{equation}
a_{n+1} = \frac{-8\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i+\sqrt{80-16\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right)^2}}{10}
\end{equation}
$\implies$
\begin{equation}
a_{n+1} = \frac{-4\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i+\sqrt{20-4\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right)^2}}{5}
\end{equation}
So we can define the recurrence relation
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
 a_1 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
 a_{n+1} = \frac{2}{5} \sqrt{5-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right)^2} - \frac{4}{5} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
And then the area $A$ that we would like to find is
\begin{equation}
A = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (a_i)^2 + \frac{3}{2}
\end{equation}
(Recall that $a_1$ and $\hat{a}_1$ are not the same hence the adjustment of $\frac{3}{2}$.

What kind of answer are you looking for? I don't think there is a "nice" expression for the result.

The convergence is fast.
